# Format an Array of Multilevel Nested-table Object to a TABLE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

DB: Oracle 11gR2

Platform: windows 7 client

Hello,

```
I have an array of multilevel nested-table object.

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE  OBJ_1 AS OBJECT (
  col_1            NUMBER,
  col_2           VARCHAR2(56),
  col_3         VARCHAR2(256)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE  ARR_1 AS TABLE OF  OBJ_1;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE  OBJ_2 AS OBJECT (
 col_4           NUMBER,
 col_5         NUMBER(15),
 col_6         NUMBER(1),
 col_7         NUMBER(1),
 col_8         VARCHAR2(56),
 col_arr       ARR_1
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE  ARR_2 AS TABLE OF  OBJ_2;
```

I want to convert to it to a table format - which I need to feed to some program. intended output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
col_4    col_5    col_6    col_7    col_8    col_1    col_2    col_3
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        2        3         4        5        1        2        3
1        2        3         4        5        4        5        6
```

On Toad the following query creates the output:

```
select *
from table(ARR_2(OBJ_2(1, 2, 3, 4, '5', ARR_1(OBJ_1(1,2,'3'))) ,
                 OBJ_2(1, 2, 3, 4, '5', ARR_1(OBJ_1(4,5,'6'))) ) )

------------------------------------------------------
col_4    col_5    col_6    col_7    col_8    col_arr
------------------------------------------------------
1        2         3        4        5       (DATASET)
1        2         3        4        5       (DATASET)
```

Where (DATASET) is the internal nested-table. So I thought adding one level to 'table function' will do the job, but NO, getting error.

```
select * from table(
select *
from table(ARR_2(OBJ_2(1, 2, 3, 4, '5', ARR_1(OBJ_1(1,2,'3'))) ,
                 OBJ_2(1, 2, 3, 4, '5', ARR_1(OBJ_1(4,5,'6'))) ) )
               );

Error: ORA-02324: more than one column in the SELECT list of THE subquery
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
select col_4, col_5, col_6, col_7, col_8, col_1, col_2, col_3
from
(
    select col_4, col_5, col_6, col_7, col_8, col_arr
    from table(ARR_2(OBJ_2(1, 2, 3, 4, '5', ARR_1(OBJ_1(1,2,'3'))) ,
                     OBJ_2(1, 2, 3, 4, '5', ARR_1(OBJ_1(4,5,'6'))) ) )
)
cross join
table(col_arr)
```